Inline images are showing as attachment in thymeleaf
try {
String emailNotificationTemplate = thymeleaf.process("email_template.html", context);
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
helper.setFrom("xyz@gmail.com");
helper.setTo(email);
helper.setSubject("Email subject");
helper.setText(emailNotificationTemplate, true);
helper.addInline("logo", new ClassPathResource("static/images/logo.png"));

mailSender.send(mimeMessage);

} catch (MessagingException e) {
}
I'm sending a mail with template using thymeleaf, all images are displaying as expected in email but the images are being attached.
Images are showing in email template but added as attachment
